# Trouble with for loop

Tags: java, animation, for-loop

I have a for loop that iterates within an actionPerformed method. Basically, I have a car game. I have a panel where car images travel from side to side in a JPanel. I am trying to have the cars stop at the finish line (I am doing that by sleeping when the image reaches a certain x value)  display the race results, leave the screen and race again. I need to do that four times until we have a winner.

```
private class RaceDisplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

   private Image img1,img2;
   private int velX1,velX2;
   private int x1,x2;
   private Timer tm;
   private JTextArea text1 = new JTextArea();


public RaceDisplay(){

        tm = new Timer(30,this);
        x1=0;
        x2=0;
        velX1=2;
        velX2 =2;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon car1 = new ImageIcon("...");
        ImageIcon car2 = new ImageIcon("...");

        img1 = car1.getImage(); 
        img2 = car2.getImage();       

        g.drawImage(img1,x1,100,null);
        g.drawImage(img2,x2,200,null);

        tm.start();

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       x1=x1+velX1;
       velX2= x2+velX2;
       repaint();

     for(int count = 0;count<=4;count++){//<-----loop with issues.
         if(count == 1){
           text1.setText(result());
          }
       if(x1>=650 && x2>=650){ //does this when both cars reach the line
          velX1=0;
          velX2=0;
          try {
             Thread.sleep(2500);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Display.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }     
          x1=0;
          x2=0;
          repaint();
          velX1= x1+velX1;
          velX2= x2+velX2;
         }

     }
       repaint();


  }
```

I created the for loop that should check the if statements when it reaches the last counter it displays the winner(method for winner in the code). I was expecting the images to travel from side to four times and display the results four times.
But it only display anything if i set the if(counter==1) to (counter==0).
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't do `tm.start();` in the `paintComponent` method.  Don't do `Thread.sleep(2500);` in your `actionPerformed` method, simply either stop the timer or stop moving the car that's passed the line

Comment: So just tm.stop() when it reaches the line?

Comment: That will stop ALL cars under the control of the `Timer`

Comment: I'm sorry, is that the problem with the loop?

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: The `Thread.sleep` is stopping the Event Dispatching Thread, not the `Timer`, it's simply preventing the EDT from processing the Event Queue which contains, amongst other things, repaint events and timer events.  Your `for-loop` is also preventing the UI from been updated, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't call `tm.start();` from within the `paintComponent` method, this is just asking for trouble.  Painting may occur for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control or have knowledge about
2. Don't call `Thread.sleep` from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  This isn't stopping the `Timer`, but is prevent the EDT from processing the Event Queue, which includes things like repaint events and timer events...

Instead, once you've detected that a car has passed the finish line, you can either, stop updating that car's position and/or stop the `Timer`

[image: Vroom]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Map<BufferedImage, Rectangle> carBounds;
        private BufferedImage blueCar;
        private BufferedImage redCar;

        public TestPane() {
            carBounds = new HashMap<>(25);
            try {
                blueCar = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/BlueCar.png"));
                redCar = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/RedCar.png"));

                int x = 0;
                int y = (200 / 2 ) - blueCar.getHeight();
                carBounds.put(blueCar, new Rectangle(x, y, blueCar.getWidth(), blueCar.getHeight()));

                y = (200 / 2);
                carBounds.put(redCar, new Rectangle(x, y, redCar.getWidth(), redCar.getHeight()));

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (BufferedImage img : carBounds.keySet()) {
                        Rectangle bounds = carBounds.get(img);

                        int xDelta = (int)Math.round((Math.random() * 7) + 1);
                        bounds.x += xDelta;
                        if (bounds.x + bounds.width > getWidth()) {
                            bounds.x = getWidth() - bounds.width;
                            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                        }

                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (BufferedImage img : carBounds.keySet()) {
                Rectangle bounds = carBounds.get(img);
                g2d.drawImage(img, bounds.x, bounds.y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Take a closer look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: great! but where would you add the loop so they do the same movement a number of times?

Comment: Why?  You only want to move them once per tick cycle, the `Timer` is a pseudo loop, each time it ticks, is another iteration